# Python import error on MacOS: `import scipy.integrate` raises `Library not loaded: ibgfortran.5.dylib`

Tags: python, macos, scipy, dylib

`echo $PATH` gives

`/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/universal-darwin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin`

After updating to MacOS Monterey `import scipy.integrate` in Python raises

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-f7ec28d1adc8> in <module>
----> 1 import scipy.integrate

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/integrate/__init__.py in <module>
     88    solve_bvp     -- Solve a boundary value problem for a system of ODEs.
     89 """
---> 90 from ._quadrature import *
     91 from .odepack import *
     92 from .quadpack import *

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/integrate/_quadrature.py in <module>
      8 # even though it's actually a NumPy function.
      9 from numpy import trapz
---> 10 from scipy.special import roots_legendre
     11 from scipy.special import gammaln
     12 

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/special/__init__.py in <module>
    631 from .sf_error import SpecialFunctionWarning, SpecialFunctionError
    632 
--> 633 from . import _ufuncs
    634 from ._ufuncs import *
    635 

ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/special/_ufuncs.cpython-39-darwin.so, 0x0002): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/10/libgfortran.5.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/special/_ufuncs.cpython-39-darwin.so
  Reason: tried: '/usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/10/libgfortran.5.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libgfortran.5.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libgfortran.5.dylib' (no such file)
```

Any idea?

Comment: What version of gcc shows `brew info gcc` inside the terminal?

Comment: gcc: stable 11.2.0, HEAD

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, it can't find `libgfortran.5.dylib` inside `/usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/10`. Since you are on gcc version 11, you can try to copy it from there via

```sh
mkdir -p /usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/10
cp /usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/11/libgfortran.5.dylib /usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/10/
```

inside a terminal.

Comment: Thanks. Now the previous error is gone, and a new similar error appears for the path `/usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/10/libquadmath.0.dylib`. I have no idea how the paths got messed up, but I'll try to adapt your answer to the new errorr.

Comment: This typically happens when upgrading gcc.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me when I upgraded my MacBook pro to MacOs ventura 13.0.1, scipy.stat didn't load. I fixed it by updating conda

```
conda update conda
```